# A question on functions

Tags: functions

Would like to get some views from you all on how you feel about the question below. For your information, it is one of the Cambridge A Level question this year. Some people said that there is an error in the question.

Functions $f$ and $g$ are defined by

$f:x\mapsto \frac{x+a}{x+b}$ for $x\in\mathbb{R},x\neq-b,a\neq-1$,

$g:x\mapsto x$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$

It is given that $ff=g$. Find the value of b.

Comment: The mistake in the question is setting $f\circ f = g$ while the domain of $f$ is only $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{ -b \}$. So, they can never be equal on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

It is a good question. I suppose by $ff$ you mean $f\circ f$. You only have to use the equation $f(f(0))=g(0)=0$ to find $b$. Besides, $f(x)=0$ only when $x =-a$ so we get $f(0)=-a$ or $\frac a b =-a$ which gives $b=-1$.

Comment: That is what I have been thinking. But some said that the given ff=g is unnecessary. Because for ff to exist, x cannot be 1 and thus b must be -1. So one can get the answer for b without using ff=g at all. Any comments?

Comment: @LanaDR That is correct. If $f(f(x))$ is defined for all $x \in \mathbb R$ then $b$ must be $-1$. But it has hard to expect this answer from many students, I guess.

Comment: Some said that the other problem is g does not have the same domain as f and therefore ff cannot be equal to g. Any comment? Is it really that important? or is it known that ff and g will only agree on the intersection of their domains?

Comment: @LanaDR This argument is also  valid. Even when $b=-1$ $f$ is not defined at $x=1$.